# Sum rows with specific criteria in r

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, data-manipulation

I am having data as

```
               function  person
1                hr       1
2                sls      5
3                mktg     3
4                qlt      7
5                rev      5
```

I want to make a row with sum of value in column "function" as "sls" and "mktg" using r programing

desired output is :

```
            Person     function
1             1         hr
2             8         sls & mktg
3             7         qlt
4             5         rev
```

Comment: is column function character string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with `dplyr`:

Code:

```
dfr %>%
  group_by(Function = sub("sls|mktg", "sls & mktg", functn)) %>%
  summarise(Person = sum(person))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Function    Person
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 hr             1.
2 qlt            7.
3 rev            5.
4 sls & mktg     8.
```

Data

`tringsAsFactors = TRUE|FALSE` - works in both cases.

```
dfr <- data.frame(
  functn   = c("hr", "sls", "mktg", "qlt", "rev"), 
  person   = c(1, 5, 3, 7, 5)                    
)
```

Comment: this works for me as I am using dplyr for my other manipulation

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution:

```
merg <- c("sls", "mktg")
dat$func[dat$func %in% merg] <- paste(merg, collapse = " & ")
aggregate(person ~ func, dat, sum)
        func person
1         hr      1
2        qlt      7
3        rev      5
4 sls & mktg      8
```

Data

```
dat <- data.frame(
  func = c("hr", "sls", "mktg", "qlt", "rev"), 
  person = c(1, 5, 3, 7, 5),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Note that this assumes `dat$func` is a character... if it is not first convert to character with `as.character()`

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(func = c("hr", "sls", "mktg", "qlt", "rev"), 
                  person = c(1, 5, 3, 7, 5))

dat %>%
  mutate(func = func %>% as.factor() %>% as.character(), 
         func = ifelse(func %in% c("sls", "mktg"), "sls & mktg", func)) %>%
  group_by(func) %>%
  summarize(Person = sum(person))
```

returns

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  func       Person
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 hr              1
2 qlt             7
3 rev             5
4 sls & mktg      8
```